# Aggregate query fails on log([data])

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, aggregate-functions

`enter code here`I'm building an aggregate query in the design view. If I average the original data, everything works just fine. As soon as I try to average log([data]) I get an error:
"Data type mismatch in criteria expression"

I'm not using any WHERE or HAVING clause in the query, so I'm not sure why it would complain about a "criteria expression". In any case, all the data (original and logged) is of type 'double', so I'm not sure where the type mismatch occurs.

I even broke out the 2 steps and set up one query that only calculates the log, with a second one (based on the first) doing the aggregation, but it throws the same error.

Would anyone have some insight? Thanks a lot!

PS: I even checked the min and max of the original data; they are all > 0.0, so taking the log of zero or a negative number is not happening either.

The code:

This works perfectly fine:

```
SELECT Tbl_00__simRecord.simID, Avg(Tbl_01__obsFlows.[obsFlow_m3/s]) AS [meanObsFlow], 
                                Min(Tbl_01__obsFlows.[obsFlow_m3/s]) AS [MinOfobsFlow_m3/s], 
                                Max(Tbl_01__obsFlows.[obsFlow_m3/s]) AS [MaxOfobsFlow_m3/s]
FROM Tbl_00__simRecord, Tbl_01__obsFlows
GROUP BY Tbl_00__simRecord.simID;
```

This, however, fails:

```
SELECT Tbl_00__simRecord.simID, Avg(Tbl_01__obsFlows.[obsFlow_m3/s])  AS [meanObsFlow], 
                                Min(Tbl_01__obsFlows.[obsFlow_m3/s])  AS [MinOfobsFlow_m3/s], 
                                Max(Tbl_01__obsFlows.[obsFlow_m3/s])  AS [MaxOfobsFlow_m3/s], 
                            Avg(Log(Tbl_01__obsFlows.[obsFlow_m3/s])) AS [meanLogObsFlow]
FROM Tbl_00__simRecord, Tbl_01__obsFlows
GROUP BY Tbl_00__simRecord.simID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have values for all logs, this works for me:

```
SELECT Table1.AText, Avg(Log([anumber])) AS Log1, Table1.ANumber
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.AText, Table1.ANumber
HAVING (((Table1.ANumber)>0));
```

Note this line Table1.ANumber>0

So you could try:

```
SELECT Tbl_00__simRecord.simID, 
   Avg(Tbl_01__obsFlows.[obsFlow_m3/s])  AS [meanObsFlow], 
   Min(Tbl_01__obsFlows.[obsFlow_m3/s])  AS [MinOfobsFlow_m3/s], 
   Max(Tbl_01__obsFlows.[obsFlow_m3/s])  AS [MaxOfobsFlow_m3/s], 
   Avg(Log(Tbl_01__obsFlows.[obsFlow_m3/s])) AS [meanLogObsFlow]
FROM Tbl_00__simRecord, Tbl_01__obsFlows
GROUP BY Tbl_00__simRecord.simID
HAVING Tbl_01__obsFlows.[obsFlow_m3/s] > 0
```

Comment: oops ... you're right, I hadn't checked for NULL values. there was one (!) null value in that data set ... and that did it. Thanks!